# How to sort the Month variable from 1 to 12? This becomes a problem when making the count cumulative, and the cumulative numbers then become wrong

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, rvest, lubridate

So i need to get the month variable sorted from 1,2,3,4...,12. At the same time the regions and years need to be separated. I have the regions and years correct, so the df is all most complete besides the date sorting is wrong.

How to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)


url <- "https://w2.brreg.no/kunngjoring/kombisok.jsp?datoFra=01.01.2019&datoTil=31.12.2019&id_region=0&id_niva1=51&id_niva2=56&id_bransje1=0"
url2 <- "https://w2.brreg.no/kunngjoring/kombisok.jsp?datoFra=01.01.2020&datoTil=31.12.2020&id_region=0&id_niva1=51&id_niva2=56&id_bransje1=0"
scraped <- Sys.time()
 
 #Scraper ut data fra URL1 og gjør om list til datasett
konkurs2019 <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//table") %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table() %>% .[[1]]
#
 konkurs2020 <- url2 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//table') %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
   html_table() %>% .[[1]]
 
 # Lager longdata
all_konkurs  <- rbind(konkurs2019,konkurs2020)
# Velger kolonner og gir nytt navn til de. 
#Bruker mutate for å putte inn ny rad "region" og fylle den raden med de gitte fylkene.
 # Filtrer vekk "Utenlands" og Orgnr med med mindre en 8 siffer (privatpersoner)
 
 all_konkurs <-select(all_konkurs,X2,X4,X6,X8)%>% 
   rename("Selskap" = X2,"Org.nummer" = X4,"Dato" = X6,"Melding" = X8) %>% 
   mutate(Fylke=ifelse(grepl("[^Dato][A-Za-z]", Dato), Dato, NA))%>%
   fill(Fylke) %>% filter(Melding == "Konkursåpning") %>% 
   filter(Fylke != "Utenlands") %>% filter(nchar(Org.nummer) >8)
 
 #rm(all_konkurs)
 # Gjør dato variabelen om fra "char" til "Date" 
 all_konkurs$Dato <- as.Date(all_konkurs$Dato,format="%d.%m.%Y")
 
 # Deler opp dato variabelen til måned og år
 all_konkurs <- all_konkurs %>% separate(Dato, into = c("Year","Month"), sep = "-")
 
# Lager en count av for antall konkurser for hver måned i hvert fylke.
 # Filterer vekk slik at jeg kun får max count for hver måned.
 all_konkurs <- all_konkurs %>% 
   group_by(Fylke,Month,Year) %>% 
   mutate(count=row_number()) %>% 
   filter(count == max(count))
 
 #Gjør "count" om til kumulative
 all_konkurs <- all_konkurs %>% group_by(Fylke,Year) %>% mutate(cm_count = cumsum(count))
 
 # Lager plot av de kumulative verdiene
all_konkurs%>% ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=cm_count, group=Year))+
          geom_line(aes(color=Year))+
          facet_wrap(~Fylke)+xlab("Måned")+ylab("Kumulativ form")+ggtitle("Konkurser i Norge")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead of `separate(Dato, into = c("Year","Month"), sep = "-")` the `lubridate` functions for extract year and month and then arrange:

```r
all_konkurs <- all_konkurs %>% 
    mutate(Year=year(Dato), Month = month(Dato)) %>% 
    arrange(Year, Month)
```